# How to get the value of lambda expression in asp .net mvc2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jradiobutton

I have a action result method where it gives values from the database and Iam passsing this values to the view and the values will be populated in the textboxes but i have radio button to be selected depending on the value of the database,example if the value is male then radiobutton as to be selected else radiobutton female aas to be selected.I have written the code

```
<% if(model=>model.Gender) {%>
             <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "Male", "Checked")%> Male
             <%} else { %>
             <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "Female", "Checked")%> Female<%} %>
```

but Iam getting a error like "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type"       .Please tel me how to check the value of Gender and make selection accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got access to the model at that point, you don't need the lambda expression at all:

```
// Or whatever
<% if (model.Gender == Gender.Male) {%>
```

However, I think it's unlikely that this is how you're *meant* to use `RadioButtonFor`. I'd expect it to be able to pick up the right button to check automatically.